# SSMS An exception has been encountered. You can get more... in file "path\AppEnv\15.0\ActivityLog.xml"

Tags: t-sql, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, ssms, visual-studio-2022

On Sunday, I planned to start work by modifying some data into backend using SSMS. But as I started the application and connected it to Azure DB, and opened the new query window the error appeared mentioned in subject line and also shown in the image attached. I thought it may be some system upgrade issue so I ignored it and continue to work, but query editor does not allowed me to write any thing. I restarted SSMS and got same error and then started looking for the options to resolve it. My SSMS version was 18.8

Things I tried

1. Reinstalling SSMS v18.8 several times.
2. Reinstalling new version of ssms 19.1 several times.
3. Updating the Extensions in Visual studio 2017.
4. Updating the Extensions in Visual studio 2019.
5. Visual studio 2022 extensions are already updated.
6. Uninstalled the Visual studio 2017.
7. Uninstalled the visual studio 2019.

I don't want to un-install the VS 2022,because I think as I understand from the error and after searching on internet as well, I found out that this error is related to Visual studio 2017, because of path "AppEnv/15.0/activitylog.xml" and 15.0 is Visual studio 2017 version number.

What I am missing? and what should I do to SSMS query editor workable?

but still no luck

[image]

[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance and please ignore my English if it is not written well.

Comment: ssms is avalable in version 19.1 so try this please

Comment: I have tried it already.

Comment: i am guessing that something went wrong somwhere, and it will be impossible, to find it. with https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer you can start and check if you can find the error, but every system produces lots and lots of entries and you need to find the needle in a haystack, easier will be to reinstall windows and make a fresh start and hope that every works out